# MultinomialNB() predicting the same category for all test documents

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a bunch of documents grouped into about 350 classes. I'm trying to build a TF-IDF multinomial model to predict the class of a new document. Everything seems to be working fine EXCEPT that the test prediction takes on only one value (even if I run the test on thousands of documents). What am I missing?

Here's the relevant code:

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")

count_vect = CountVectorizer()

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(norm='l1', use_idf=True, smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=False)

clf = MultinomialNB()    

mycsv = pd.read_csv("C:/DocumentsToClassify.csv", encoding='latin-1')

Document_text=mycsv.document.str.lower()
y=mycsv.document_group

Y=[]
stemmed_documents = []

for i in range(0, 50000 ,2):
    tokenized_document = tokenizer.tokenize(Document_text[i])

    stemmed_document = ""

    for w in tokenized_document:
        if w not in stop_words:
            w = re.sub(r'\d+', '', w)
            if w is not None:
                stemmed_document=stemmed_document+" "+stemmer.stem(w)

    stemmed_documents=np.append(stemmed_documents,stemmed_document)
    Y=np.append(Y,y[i])

Y_correct=[]
test_documents = []
for i in range(1,50000,4):
    tokenized_document = tokenizer.tokenize(Document_text[i])      
    stemmed_document = ""
    for w in tokenized_document:
        if w not in stop_words:
            w = re.sub(r'\d+', '', w)
            if w is not None:
                stemmed_document=stemmed_document+" "+stemmer.stem(w)

    test_documents=np.append(test_documents,stemmed_document)
    Y_correct=np.append(Y_correct,y[i])

Word_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(stemmed_documents)
Words_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(Word_counts)

Word_counts_test = count_vect.transform(test_documents)
Words_tfidf_test = tfidf_transformer.transform(Word_counts_test)

# Training
clf.fit(Words_tfidf, Y)

# Test
Ynew=clf.predict(Words_tfidf_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this for a while yesterday, I figured out a solution - switching from MultinomialNB() to SGDClassifier(). I'm not sure why it wasn't working with MultinomialNB(), but SDG works great. Here's the relevant - and much shortened - code (closely following http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(norm='l1', use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False)),
                     ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, random_state=42)),
])

# Training dataset
train_data = pd.read_csv("A:/DocumentsWithGroupTrain.csv", encoding='latin-1')

# Test dataset
test_data = pd.read_csv("A:/DocumentsWithGroupTest.csv", encoding='latin-1')

text_clf.fit(train_data.document, train_data.doc_group)
predicted = text_clf.predict(test_data.document)
print(np.mean(predicted == test_data.doc_group))
```